# Ring structure on tensor product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I previously asked a question on whether isomorphisms of modules could be somehow translated into isomorphisms of rings, in order to find that

$$U^{1}R\otimes V^{-1}R \simeq U^{-1}(V^{-1}R)$$

as rings, for $U$,$V$ multiplicative subsets, and $R$ a ring. My idea was to use the map $\frac{a/b}{c} \mapsto (\frac{1}{c} \otimes \frac{a}{b}$) from right to left and prove that it's indeed a homomorphism (and then bijective). However, when trying to to do so is when I realised that I don't even have a ring multiplication on $U^{1}R\otimes V^{-1}R$. I don't even know if it is a ring. I tried a little, and I found that if I define a multiplication

$$(a \otimes b) \cdot(c \otimes d) = (ac) \otimes (bd)$$

and consider $(1\otimes 1)$ the identity with respect to that operation, that I get a ring structure with the usual addition on tensor products. But then I also realized that you could get another ring structure by defining a different addition by

$$(a \otimes b) +(c \otimes d) = (a+c) \otimes (b+d)$$

which gets rid of the structure of the tensor product as an $R$-module, but since what I'm trying to do is getting a ring isomorphism, it might be worth the try. I tried looking up if there is a standard, conventional way of defining a ring structure on a tensor product of rings, but couldn't find anything. Is there some sort of canonical ring structure on the tensor product of two rings?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras. (I guess you are looking at the tensor product of rings viewed as $\Bbb{Z}$-algebras, so your $R \otimes S$ is $R \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} S$.)

Comment: @RobArthan The OP meant $\otimes_R$ (ie. $rar_2\otimes b=a\otimes r_1br_2$ for $r_1,r_2\in R$, not sure if we need to assume they commute with the other elements, as suggested by the word $R$-algebra). The multiplication is always defined by $(a \otimes b) \cdot(c \otimes d) = (ac) \otimes (bd)$, and the addition is defined in term of bilinearity: $(a+b)\otimes c=a\otimes c+b\otimes c$.

Comment: @reuns: I see, so the OP is looking at things like $A \otimes_R B$ where $A$ and $B$ are subrngs of $R$. The definitions in the wikipedia page stilll apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think to make things concrete you should try with $R= \Bbb{Z},U= <2>,V=<3>$, $$U^{-1}R = \Bbb{Z}[2^{-1}]=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1),\qquad V^{-1}R=\Bbb{Z}[y]/(3y-1)$$
$$U^{-1}R\otimes_R V^{-1}R=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2x-1)\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Z}[y]/(3y-1)\cong \Bbb{Z}[x,y]/(2x-1,3y-1)$$

At first you can think to the tensor product of rings as the thing making (for $R$ commutative) $R[X]/I\otimes_R R[Y]/J\cong R[X,Y]/(I,J)$.